# Calling function from another model in wizard, Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15

I can call the function from another model in wizard. But there is a problem. When i call the function from another model, I can't use the fields.

Calling function code:

```
self.env['inventory.menu'].action_delete()
```

Function from another model:

```js
    def action_delete(self):
        print("girdi", self.price)
        vals = {
            'ref_code': self.ref_code,
            'products_id': self.products_id.id,
            'product_description': self.product_description,
            'teslim_alan': self.teslim_alan,
            'teslim_eden': self.teslim_eden,
            'quantity': self.scrap_quantity,
            'price': self.price,
            'unit_price': self.unit_price,
            'warehouse_id': self.warehouse_id.id
        }
        self.env['scrap'].create(vals)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
The operation cannot be completed:
- Create/update: a mandatory field is not set.
- Delete: another model requires the record being deleted. If possible, archive it instead.
```

How can i solve that? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling it on an empty recordset (`self.env['inventory.menu']`). If you want to use values of a record/instance, you probably should get one first.

Let's assume you have a Many2one field on a wizard like in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73046610/getting-id-from-url-to-filling-wizard-form-odoo) and you press a button on that wizard, calling the wizards method `action_do`:

```py
def action_do(self):
    # self is the wizard record/instance
    # do other things before
    self.inventory_id.action_delete()
    # do other things afterwards
```

Also have in mind, if calling on multi recordsets (one2many, many2many) always think about looping about the records. Either in your action method or in an outer scope.